# Every post besides first post doesn't have background color and space between the posts in posting system PHP

Tags: php, html, css

So, I have a posting system. Now, there's an `input` field and a post `button` and when you click the post `button`, the post gets displayed (whatever you typed in the `input` field). Now, the first post has a background color (`background-color`) of Silver, `#C0C0C0`. However, any other post, like the second post or the third post don't have a background color at all. How can I fix this, and give every post, whether it's the first post or any other post, a background color of Silver?

Also, if you have multiple posts, the vertical space between the posts is very small. How can I increase the space between the posts as well?

The code for the post:

```
<div class="textPost">
  <?php

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM posts";
  $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
  if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

  ?>
  <div class="textpostFormat">
    <-- All the post content (body, like button, etc.) -->
  </div>
  <?php

  }
}

  ?>
</div>
```

CSS styling for the post:

```
<style media="screen">

.textPost {
  margin-top: 170px;
  width: 650px;
  height: 400px;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #C0C0C0;
  margin-left: 685px;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.textpostFormat {
  margin-left: -640px;
  position: fixed;
}

</style>
```

How can I fix this issue? Please help. Thank you!!

Comment: `<div method="post" …` is not valid HTML markup, are you trying to use a `<form>` element? Also, please provide some sort of overview to get an idea of your setup structure, where is your `<style>` located, can you insert a screenshot illustrating the problem of the webpage?

Comment: Sorry, did not mean to put `<div method="post">`. No, it's not a form tag, it's a `div` only. Just accidentally included that `method="post"` and that `action="yourposts.php"`. My style is located right under that `<div class="textPost">`. Check my edited question for the screenshot of what's happening.

Comment: I see, is there any reason for using `position: fixed`?

Comment: No, not really.

Comment: You tried it without?

Comment: Well, what does it do? What will trying it without do?

Comment: Using `fiexed` elements will cause your browser to render them with a different layout model than normally for `block` or `inline` elements. I would suggest commenting out these lines and give it a try, because I don't think you need it here.

Comment: Ok, I commented out that line `position: fixed`. It didn't do anything.